# About variational principles

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, variational-principle

Is there any way one can modify a known functional so as to get a solution for another quantity related to it? Because this is too general I would like to make it more clear with an example. Given the classical EM Lagrangian, we acquire the equations of motion for a particle in an EM field. Starting from this, is there anyway one can find a functional that when varied will give the solution for, let us say, the electric potential, for a given charge distribution and known boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning OP's example: The Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation for the energy functional $E[\phi]=\int\!d^3x\left( \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2 -\rho\phi\right)$ is [Poisson's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) $\nabla^2\phi=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$.